# Creating sumproduct along with groupby in Python from an imported excel file

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which has data about its stock prices. There are 4 columns Ticker,Data,Prices and number of units traded. I have successfully imported the data in Python and now I need multiply the price with number of units for each ticker. There are 10 categories of TICKER and 33900 observations in the excel file. I need to write a function in Python which multiplies Price and No of units traded for every date and group by the ticker value.
i have done sofar :
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'E:\ Assignment\InputData_test1a_Py.xlsx', sheet_name='RawData')
print (df).
Please suggest the function definition for this.
[image]

Comment: Instead of posting an image, post a table so that others can easily recreate your dataframe.

Comment: Sure, Let me try

Comment: @Toukenize I am not able to insert table, can you guide

Comment: Try copying your table content into Stackoverflow, then select your table content, followed by `Ctrl+K`

Comment: @Toukenize It isn't working

Comment: Try referring to the guide here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-to-create-a-table-in-a-post

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you require correctly, this should solve your problem:

```
# Generate a dataframe that is similar to yours
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Ticker':[f'Id{i}' for i in range(1,8,1)],
        'Date':['03-Jan-07'] * 7,
        'Prices':[95,989,110,125,160,240,333],
        'Close Units':[num / 10_000 for num in range(1,8,1)]
    }
)

# Assign new column Value, which is the product of Prices and Close Units
# groupby and sum
df_out = (
    df
    .assign(Value = df['Prices'] * df['Close Units'])
    .groupby(['Ticker','Date'])
    ['Value']
    .sum()
)
```

And you should get the sumproduct groupby `Ticker` and `Date`

```
                    Value
Ticker  Date    
Id1     03-Jan-07   0.0095
Id2     03-Jan-07   0.1978
Id3     03-Jan-07   0.0330
Id4     03-Jan-07   0.0500
Id5     03-Jan-07   0.0800
Id6     03-Jan-07   0.1440
Id7     03-Jan-07   0.2331
```

Comment: what is ['Value'] doing ?

Comment: select the column to apply your `sum` on

Comment: i want to export the df_out to an excel file, i m getting the following error:
df.to_excel(r'E:\ Assignment\InputData_test1a_Py.xlsx', sheet_name='OutputFormat', index = False,header=True)
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
E:\Anaconda\AnacondaSetup\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py in close(self)
    319             try:
--> 320                 self._store_workbook()
    321             except IOError as e:

Comment: @ Toukenize with your solution i m getting all 33900 observation i want them to be grouped in categories as there are 10 stocks

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Amount'] = df['Close Units'] * df['Prices']
df.groupby(['Ticker', 'Date'])['Amount'].sum()
```

Comment: I want the time series plot for index level and want to save it as 
 pdf. the code till here is :
  df['IndexLevel']=df['Prices']*df['Close Units']
df['IndexLevel']=df['IndexLevel'].cumsum()
print(df)